# DNS Conditional forwarders being ignored on one of DC's

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We've got a 2 domain controllers on Windows 2008 R2 (migrated from 2003). Replication works fine and everything seems to work just fine but we noticed one of DC's (and DNS for that matter) seems to ignore Conditional Forwarders for our test domains and it directly ask Internet DNS so it gets different values then it should. Each DC points to each other and itself only and they have set Forwarders set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Conditional forwarders are set to some local IP addresses.

I've seen this kind of of problem for 2003 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953419/en-us) but it doesn't seem to mention 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out one of the DC's had EnableDnsProbes set to 1. As soon as I set it to 0 on both and cleaned cache and restarted DNS Server/NetLogon on both controlers everything seems to resolve good.

```
dnscmd /config /enableednsprobes 0
```

As per [Microsoft Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc787130%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).